# How to turn on line numbering on modes that doesn't have by default?

Tags: spacemacs, line-numbers

I have spacemacs and when I edit a `.py` or `.c` file line numbering is turned on no problem, however when I open a `.R` file it isn't there (the mode is named `ESS[S]` to be precise). How can I turn it on here too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to turn `linum-mode` on after starting `ess-mode`. This mode takes care of adding line numbers.

`(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook 'linum-mode)`